# How can one disable Wi-Fi power management when using Jupiter?

Tags: wireless, power-management, freeze, jupiter

**Background and Problem**

My laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad `X131e 3372-2VU`, running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) freezes when Ubuntu tries to manage the wireless interface's power.

I had to manually disable wireless power management to prevent the freezes, and it never happens ever since I did.

However, now I use `jupiter` in order to save battery while not on AC power, and it seems that wireless power management is back on, and the system freezes started happening again.

Is there a way to configure `jupiter` to not manage wireless interface power? Or is it enough to just disable the power management manually (i.e. `jupiter` won't turn it back on again)?

The `jupiter` applet has been doing an excellent job otherwise. It has literally doubled my laptop's battery life. So I'd much rather have `jupiter` around.

**Symptoms**

Running `iwconfig` on boot would show the following, even after manually setting wireless power management off (`sudo iwconfig eth2 power off`) before rebooting or shutting down:

```
eth2      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"287LyonSt."  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: F8:D1:11:9B:89:81   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research and some luck (there weren't many information on the internet as to how one can fiddle with `jupiter` configurations), I was able to find my own answer.

If you look into `/usr/bin/jupiter`, which is written in `python`, it tells us that `jupiter` runs all `power-management` related shell scripts from 2 files in `/usr/lib/jupiter/kernel/`:

- `battery` for scripts run when the laptop is on battery.
- `power` for scripts run when the laptop is on AC power.

To stop `jupiter` from turning on `power-management` for your wireless interface card, do the following:

1. Find the line that says: `iw dev $WIFI_ADAPTER set power_save on`
2. Change it to: `iw dev $WIFI_ADAPTER set power_save off`

Answer (score 0):

This directory containg the ubuntu 12.04 lst default power mananager

`/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/`

Inside a "wireless" executable file has logic to enable, disable wireless on AC/Battery or safe more.